# How to pass Dynamic class name inside of the Class.forName()?

Tags: java, android

I have to send class name inside `Class.forName(myclass)` but it does not work because my class names are fully dynamic values.
when i pass like this `Class.forName("com.example.myapp.myclassname")` its working fine. but when i try to pass the class name as dynamic one it does not working.
i get class name from db and stored in string variable and pass that variable into `forName()` method but its always return Class not found error.

what i tried,

classDefinition = Class.forName("com.example.MyPack.MyApp.MyClass"); // **its working fine**

but
**it does not working** when i pass the string inside the `forName(string)`, **string is hold the class path(fully qualified value)**

```
function demo(String className){

    String dynamicClass = className;
    classDefinition = Class.forName(dynamicClass );
}
```

Comment: "string is hold the class path"  <-- What do you call the class path here ?

Comment: string hold the value like this com.example.myapp.myclassname . . .here myclassname is dynamic here . . it will change based on the condition

Comment: Do you have in mind that case matters?

Comment: can you please clear i dont understand what you are asking

Comment: In correspondence to comment by @TimothyTruckle, have you tried using `.equals` to compare explicit string and dynamic one?

Comment: i have only dynamic values no need to compare these values  ..i need to pass the string value inside the forName() . .

Comment: Yes, I understand that you need to pass only dynamic one, but what we are trying to exclude is an option that dynamic string is not properly formatted. So, in whatever way you're constructing dynamic string, you can debug by compering it to what value you expect it to have.

Comment: can you show the log for the file name you are passing in Class.forName(dynamicClass )

Comment: oh okay checked both are not same . but when i print these two values same values printed i dont knw why its not equal one. and when i pass the value to forName() its workiing . when i store the value into variable and pass that variable it does not working

Comment: Try using `.trim` on dynamic String. If that doesn't work, loop through characters in both strings and compare them to find out which characters are at fault.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava ,

LoG:

D/NO: NOT EQUAL
com.example.djaxtech.newdjaxdemoapp.Admobbanner
com.example.djaxtech.newdjaxdemoapp.Admobbanner

04-17 15:29:30.957 5216-5216/com.example.djaxtech.newdjaxdemoapp W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: com.example.djaxtech.newdjaxdemoapp.Admobbanner

Comment: now update your question with package name and Admobbanner.class code

Comment: it does not problem we can check with any names with package .

Comment: okay i will check with trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix error using **trim** method to remove the unwanted space and got working like charm .